# Stop a textarea element leaving its parent?

Tags: html, css

I have the following code:

```
<html>
    <body style="background-color:#800000;">
        <div style="background-color:#000;margin:0 auto;height:800px;width:800px;">
            <textarea style="background-color:#666666;"></textarea>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

As you can see, it has a dark red background, a black `div` and a grey `textarea` element. When I resize the `textarea`, the following happens: https://i.imgur.com/sfwTtd5.gifv. Even though the `textarea` is clearly inside the `div` (it's parent), it is still leaving it. How can I make it so the `textarea` cannot have a bigger width or height than its parent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set a `max-width`and a `max-height`.

```html
<html>
    <body style="background-color:#800000;">
        <div style="background-color:#000;margin:0 auto;height:300px;width:300px;">
            <textarea style="background-color:#666666;max-width:100%;max-height:100%;"></textarea>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ok, thankyou, that fixes it mostly. However, this behaviour still happens when I zoom in. Any way to stop that? (I'll accept it as soon as I can - in 11 mins)

Comment: @carefulnow can you explain what you mean by zooming?

Comment: i dont get that behavior on chrome on mac.

Comment: Zooming the browser window. E.g. in Chrome, Control+Scroll Up. EDIT: Ah nevermind, it was an something else causing it. Thanks for the help, I'll accept asap